# Stacking await keywords

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates

I am trying to reduce the boiler plate code from getting data from my cache repository. I was basically copying and pasting the same code over and over, so I put all of that logic into a new class, CacheReadCommand. I am trying to do this using async/await as my database repository has already implemented async/await. What has ended up happening is that I got this stack of await keywords when I am trying to execute CacheReadCommand.Read. This is not actually returning anything and leaving the application hung up. Where did I go wrong here?

**CacheReadCommand**

```
public class CacheReadCommand : ICacheReadCommand {
    private readonly ICacheRepository _repo;

    public CacheReadCommand(ICacheRepository repo) {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<T> Read<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> query) {
        T retVal = await _repo.GetValue<T>(cacheKey);

        if(retVal == null) {
            retVal = query.Invoke();

            if(retVal != null) {
                await _repo.SetValue<T>(cacheKey, retVal);
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

** Settings Repository **

```
    public async Task<Setting> GetSetting(Guid guid, string key) {
        string cacheKey = $"GetSetting_{guid}_{key}";

        return await await _readCommand.Read(cacheKey, async () => await ReadOne<Setting>("GetSetting", guid));
    }

    protected async Task<T> ReadOne<T>(string sql, Guid siteGuid) {
        DynamicParameters parms = new DynamicParameters();
        parms.Add(PARMNAME_GUID, siteGuid.ToFormattedString());

        return await ReadOne<T>(GetCommandDefinition(sql, parms));
    }
```

Comment: The `await await` doesn't make sense. This shouldn't compile. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity It makes perfect sense and compiles just fine whenever the expression following it is a `Task<Task<T>>` (or Task<Task>), which is the case here.

Comment: If you want to give an async query to your `Read` function, you need to ask explicitly for a `Func<Task<T>>` and await it. Right now you're calling `Invoke()` on the delegate, which returns a `Task<Setting>` and you give it as-is to your repository. I'm fairly certain that this is not what you want

Comment: @Servy - Yes, but there's no double task here as far as I can see?

Comment: @KevinGosse implementing Func<Task<T>> did alleviate the second await, however I am still using query.Invoke(). I just have to await that. I have compiled it and tested it. That worked. This solution works for me, if you want to put your comment as an answer, I'll close it.

Comment: @KevinGosse apparently, I don't know what I am talking about. I learned that I do not need to use the invoke method. I am still learning my way around action/func delegates.

Comment: @fizch You can use invoke if you prefer. I was just trying to say that you needed to await the return value :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give an async query to your Read function, you need to ask explicitly for a `Func<Task<T>>` and await it. Right now you're calling Invoke() on the delegate, which returns a `Task<Setting>`.

So instead you should do something like:

```
public async Task<T> Read<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> query) {
    T retVal = await _repo.GetValue<T>(cacheKey);

    if(retVal == null) {
        retVal = await query();

        if(retVal != null) {
            await _repo.SetValue<T>(cacheKey, retVal);
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```